# Submit id value from displaytag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, displaytag, ognl

I generate some table using DisplayTag library and Struts2. And I need to post object id in form because I need to know what object I should delete.

Here is my code:

```
<display:table name="clients" id="client">
    <display:column sortable="true" property="id" title="ID"/>
    <display:column sortable="true" property="name" title="Name"/>
    <display:column sortable="true" property="surname" title="Surname"/>
    <display:column sortable="true" property="age" title="Age"/>
    <display:column sortable="true" property="email" title="e-mail"/>
    <display:column sortable="true" property="sex" title="Sex"/>
    <display:column>
        <s:form action="delete" method="GET">
            <s:hidden key="client" value="${client_rowNum}"></s:hidden>
            <s:submit value="Delete"/>
        </s:form>
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```

Exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /pages/clientList.jsp(23,12) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:148)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1209)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:846)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:865)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:865)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:865)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2417)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1763)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:164)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:546)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
```

but when I try to launch it it throw exception, if you know please help me to understand how to do it.

Comment: What is an exception is thrown?

Comment: You shouldn't use EL `${}` inside the struts tag attribute `value` use OGNL `%{}` instead.

Comment: I tried but if I use %{client.id} it doesn't set any value

Comment: You need to change a code little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<display:table name="clients" id="client" uid="row">
    <display:column sortable="true" property="id" title="ID"/>
    <display:column sortable="true" property="name" title="Name"/>
    <display:column sortable="true" property="surname" title="Surname"/>
    <display:column sortable="true" property="age" title="Age"/>
    <display:column sortable="true" property="email" title="e-mail"/>
    <display:column sortable="true" property="sex" title="Sex"/>
    <display:column>
        <s:form action="delete" method="GET">
            <s:hidden key="client[%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}]" value="%{#attr.row.id}"></s:hidden>
            <s:submit value="Delete"/>
        </s:form>
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```